# Auto Layout - Is there a way to set a "symbolic" breakpoint for ambiguous views?

Tags: xcode5, autolayout

I've grown accustom to having symbolic breakpoints for exceptions etc, and I'm wondering if there's clever way to set a break point in Xcode that would trip when a view is marked as ambiguous by auto layout.

When constraints can't be satisfied, you get a wall of text in console, but when they are ambiguous the problem isn't noisy enough.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a symbolic breakpoint with the symbol `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` but it won't stop for ambiguous ones, also because I think that `UIKit` automatically adds constraints based on the view's frame to remove ambiguousness

EDIT:

you can still put symbolic breakpoints on `hasAmbiguousLayout` (`UIView` method) and put the condition that it returns true. Or put a breakpoint wherever you want that stops when that method returns `YES`

Comment: I know how to put a symbolic breakpoint on `-[UIView hasAmbiguousLayout]`, but I don't know how to set a conditional on it.

Comment: This should help you http://staxmanade.com/2015/06/debugging-ios-autolayout-issues/